# TypeError: data is undefined when using jquery.datatables.min.js

Tags: javascript, datatables

"I am able to see the server side ajax results, but I am receiving a JS error on screen.

There are no null values in the result.

But, the below mentioned error is thrown.

DataTables warning: table id=summaryResults1 - Requested unknown parameter 'workCategory' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4"

```
summaryTable = $('#summaryResults1').DataTable( {

                              data: tableResultsAjax,
                              serverSide: true,
                              ajax: {
                                    dataSrc: function (json) {
                                          return json.data;
                                      },
                                    "data": function(){
                                        var info = $('#summaryResults1').DataTable().page.info();

                                         $('#summaryResults1').DataTable().ajax.url(
                                                url_ajax+"&bucketCounter="+(info.page+1)
                                            );

                                    }

                              },

                              paging:true,
                              pageLength:500,
                              scrollX:true,
                              scrollCollapse: true,
                              ordering: false,
                              "scrollY": 1000,
                              "lengthChange": false,
                              "searching": false,
                              "deferRender":true,

                   "columns": [
                              { "data": "workCategory" },
                              { "data": "queue" },
                              ....

                              ],

                        columnDefs : [ {
                                "targets" : [  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 ],
                                "render" : function(data, type, row,meta) {
                                    if (type === "display" ) {
                                        param = 20-meta.col;
                                        return drilldownViewCheck?data:"<a id = 'aa' href=\"javascript:passAJAXValues('" + row.queue.code + "','" + row.task.code + "','P"+param+"','"+ row.office.code + "')\"style=\"color:#FFF;\">" + data + "</a>";
                                    }
                                }
                            },

                            ....
                          ],

                        fixedColumns:{
                              leftColumns:6
                          }





                      } );
 });
```

The server side response for one row is

{"recordsFiltered":750,"data":"[{....,\"workCategory\":\"Work category\",....,\"queue\":\"Queue Name\"}]","draw":2,"recordsTotal":750}

Answer (score 1):

[Technical note #4](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4#Parameter-is-a-string) states the problem precisely:

> This will indicate that a column which uses `columns.data` has been
>   unable to obtain valid data to display - for example:
>
> ```
> { data: 'Name' }
> ```
>
> would produce this error if the data source object for the row had no `Name`
>   parameter or the data was `null` or `undefined`.

Your response from the server-side script most likely do not have `workCategory` property.

In your response your `data` property is encoded into JSON format twice on the server, that is why DataTables is not finding any data, because `data` is a string and should be array.

Comment: I have checked the server side script already in the Network(Developer tools). All the fields that are mentioned are present.

Comment: @sashi, please post response from your server-side script

Comment: Edited the post. You can find the server side response there.

Comment: I have removed the dataSrc and tested. No luck!

Comment: @shashi, your `data` is encoded into JSON format twice on the server, that is why DataTables is not finding any data, because `data` is a string and should be Array.

Comment: I got your point! But I am still missing something."TypeError: c is undefined" is the error now.

Comment: @shashi, possibly that is because number of `th` elements in the table header or footer differs from number of columns in the table body or defined using `columns` option, but there could be other reasons as well.

Comment: Issue resolved. I added a 'dataSrc' as 'data', and changed the server side response to JSON Object. Server side response is the same as  above. Thanks a lot!!!